# MULE ESB - Error HTTPS, received EOFException: error

Tags: https, jboss, mule

I have MULE ESB deployed in JBoss server 7.0.1 configured with HTTPS connector:

```
<https:inbound-endpoint address="https://${ws.host}:8443/services" path="services" exchange-    pattern="request-response" connector-ref="httpConnector" responseTimeout="${ws.timeout}">
  <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="..." >
  </cxf:jaxws-service>
  <transformer ref="..." />
</https:inbound-endpoint>
<https:connector name="httpConnector">
        <https:tls-key-store path="/tmp/keystore.jks" keyPassword="pass" storePassword="passs"/>
        <!--https:tls-server path="/tmp/trustStore.jks" storePassword="pass"/-->
</https:connector>
```

The client Side is using gSoap Version 1.3.

When calling web service, received error, these are logs of JBoss server:

```
20:11:39,498 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.01) Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
20:11:39,499 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.01) Allow legacy hello messages: true
20:11:39,499 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.01) Is initial handshake: true
20:11:39,499 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.01) Is secure renegotiation: false
20:11:39,509 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, received EOFException: error
20:11:39,509 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
20:11:39,510 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
20:11:39,510 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
20:11:39,510 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) [Raw write]: length = 7
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) 0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 28                               ......(
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, called closeSocket()
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, called close()
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, called closeInternal(true)
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, called close()
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, called closeInternal(true)
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, called close()
20:11:39,511 INFO  [stdout] (httpConnector.receiver.02) httpConnector.receiver.02, called closeInternal(true)
20:11:39,516 ERROR [org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy] (httpConnector.receiver.02) Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Remote host closed connection during handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882) [:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188) [:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:818) [:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75) [:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:50) [:1.6]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78) [commons-httpclient-3.1-osgi.jar:]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106) [commons-httpclient-3.1-osgi.jar:]
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readLine(HttpServerConnection.java:219) [mule-transport-http-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readRequest(HttpServerConnection.java:185) [mule-transport-http-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:155) [mule-transport-http-3.2.1.jar:]
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310) [mule-core-3.2.1.jar:]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462) [:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863) [:1.6]
    ... 13 more
```

**Is there a compatibility problem between gSoap 1.3 and JBoss?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why running in JBoss if you don't use its HTTP/HTTPS layer?

Comment: We are using JBoss only for MULE (there is no server.xml file) only Mule configuration is used

Comment: But you deploy Mule as a web-app, right?

Comment: Yes, we deploy Mule as a web-app

Comment: OK, the reason I'm asking is that in that case it makes little sense to have Mule start its own HTTP server within the web-app and it's more logical to just connect Mule to the web container via the servlet container. This is tangential to the discussion but keep this in mind.

Comment: OK thank you for this idea, this is another use case of Mule + JBoss, but should I connect Mule to the web container to run Mule in HTTPS?

Comment: It would be more correct to use the HTTP/HTTPS layer from JBoss yes, but your current approach should work too, it's just less satisfying in the sense that Mule is running a web container within a web container..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the client side has access to the same certificate.

EDIT: Remove `path="services"` from the `http:inbound-endpoint` as it's useless since you provide a full `address` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, the client side is using OpenSSL and is using the same certificate in PEM format generated form JKS file using the following comments:
    [keytool -export -alias mule -keystore keystore.jks -file exported-der.crt] and 
    [openssl x509 -in exported-der.crt -out exported-pem.crt -outform pem -inform der]

Comment: it's indicating SOAP Error Code 30 but my password contains numbers and letters

Comment: Can you retrieve the WSDL over HTTPS with curl or your browser? Try getting `https://${ws.host}:8443/services?wsdl`. Also have you tried SOAPui? Just trying to diagnose the issue further.

Comment: Yes I can retrieve the WSDL over HTTPS, I haven't tried with SaopUI I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: Nice, so it seems SSL is correctly set up on the Mule side of things. Something broken on the gSoap side then?

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the gSoap side, we are checking the client, thank you!